# glPolygonOffset with unexpected lines

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am rendering triangle strips with glpolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE).
Then I enable the line offset to this setting glPolygonOffset (-0.8f, -1.0f).

No matter what setting I use for the offset I end up getting random lines that flash
in and out when moving around. Here is a gif. of what it looks like. If anyone could help
give ideas as what they think is wrong here that would be great.

[image]

Here is my method where I render the lines if anyone needs to look at it.

```
public void lines() {
    GL11.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    GL11.glPolygonMode(GL11.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL11.GL_LINE);       

    Triangle currentTri = new Triangle();
    List<Triangle> triList = new ArrayList<Triangle>();                               
    boolean xSwitch = false;

    for (int z=0; z<=100; z+=2) {
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE);
        GL11.glPolygonOffset (-0.8f, -1.0f);

        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

        int triPointIndex = 0;
        boolean zSwitch = true;
        xSwitch = !xSwitch;
        float zVal;
        float xVal;

        for (int x=0; x<100; x+=1) {
            xVal = x;
            float randY;
            zSwitch = !zSwitch;    

            // this is what determines the xSwitch and zSwitch outcomes.
            // changes the zVal and randY to match what must alternate.
            if (xSwitch) {
                if (zSwitch) {
                    zVal = z;
                    randY = randYList[z][x];
                } else {
                    zVal = z + 2.0f;
                    randY = randYList[z+2][x];
                }
            } else {                        
                if (zSwitch) {
                    zVal = z + 2.0f;
                    randY = randYList[z+2][x];
                } else {
                    zVal = z;
                    randY = randYList[z][x];
                }
            }   

            // set up the currentVert within the currentTri so that we can use it for computing normals.
            Vert currentVert = currentTri.triVerts[triPointIndex];
            currentVert.x = xVal;
            currentVert.y = randY;
            currentVert.z = zVal;
            triPointIndex++;

            if (triPointIndex == 3) {
                triList.add(currentTri);
                Triangle nextTri = new Triangle();

                Vector3f normal = new Vector3f();
                float Ux; float Uy; float Uz;
                float Vx; float Vy; float Vz;

                if (xSwitch) {
                    if (triList.indexOf(currentTri) % 2 == 0) {
                        Vx = currentTri.triVerts[1].x - currentTri.triVerts[0].x;
                        Vy = currentTri.triVerts[1].y - currentTri.triVerts[0].y;
                        Vz = currentTri.triVerts[1].z - currentTri.triVerts[0].z;

                        Ux = currentTri.triVerts[2].x - currentTri.triVerts[0].x;
                        Uy = currentTri.triVerts[2].y - currentTri.triVerts[0].y;
                        Uz = currentTri.triVerts[2].z - currentTri.triVerts[0].z;               
                    } else {
                        Ux = currentTri.triVerts[1].x - currentTri.triVerts[0].x;
                        Uy = currentTri.triVerts[1].y - currentTri.triVerts[0].y;
                        Uz = currentTri.triVerts[1].z - currentTri.triVerts[0].z;

                        Vx = currentTri.triVerts[2].x - currentTri.triVerts[0].x;
                        Vy = currentTri.triVerts[2].y - currentTri.triVerts[0].y;
                        Vz = currentTri.triVerts[2].z - currentTri.triVerts[0].z;   
                    }
                } else {
                    if (triList.indexOf(currentTri) % 2 == 0) {
                        Ux = currentTri.triVerts[1].x - currentTri.triVerts[0].x;
                        Uy = currentTri.triVerts[1].y - currentTri.triVerts[0].y;
                        Uz = currentTri.triVerts[1].z - currentTri.triVerts[0].z;

                        Vx = currentTri.triVerts[2].x - currentTri.triVerts[0].x;
                        Vy = currentTri.triVerts[2].y - currentTri.triVerts[0].y;
                        Vz = currentTri.triVerts[2].z - currentTri.triVerts[0].z;   
                    } else {
                        Vx = currentTri.triVerts[1].x - currentTri.triVerts[0].x;
                        Vy = currentTri.triVerts[1].y - currentTri.triVerts[0].y;
                        Vz = currentTri.triVerts[1].z - currentTri.triVerts[0].z;

                        Ux = currentTri.triVerts[2].x - currentTri.triVerts[0].x;
                        Uy = currentTri.triVerts[2].y - currentTri.triVerts[0].y;
                        Uz = currentTri.triVerts[2].z - currentTri.triVerts[0].z;
                    }
                }

                normal.x = (Uy * Vz) - (Uz * Vy);
                normal.y = (Uz * Vx) - (Ux * Vz);
                normal.z = (Ux * Vy) - (Uy * Vx);

                GL11.glNormal3f(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);

                nextTri.triVerts[0] = currentTri.triVerts[1];
                nextTri.triVerts[1] = currentTri.triVerts[2];
                currentTri = nextTri;

                triPointIndex = 2;
            } // close triPointIndex == 3 
            GL11.glVertex3f(xVal, randY, zVal);
        } // close x loop
        GL11.glEnd();
    } // close z loop
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE);

}
```

Comment: Are you aware that you are leaking your polygon mode when you do this? You change it to `GL_LINE` when the function starts and never set it to anything else before it returns. Those errant lines may be the result of drawing that occurs after this function is called. It is also possible that you are seeing strip resets due to degenerate triangles considering your primitive type is `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`... you might consider drawing your polygons using `GL_POINT` for the mode to see what is really going on.

Comment: thank you, I tried it with GL_POINT like you suggested and the same appearance happens, but instead with points randomly popping up. What do you mean by "strip resets due to degenerate triangles"?

Comment: Well, `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` is a connected primitive. That is, it shares vertices. Ordinarily if you drew a bunch of vertices with this primitive mode, they would all be connected. However, if you ever create a situation where one of the triangles has ***zero area*** (degenerate), it has the effect that the next vertex you specify will not be connected to the strip. When done intentionally, this is called "primitive restart". When done unintentionally, it is usually called random noise ;) If you were using vertex arrays, one common cause of this is drawing more elements than your array stores.

Comment: You are not using vertex arrays, however. So if that is what is going on here, your loop would be to blame. That loop has way too many branches for me to want to debug without running the code. But I suspect you may have handled a case incorrectly and/or may be inserting one or more more points than you need.

Comment: Have you tried drawing this with a plain old triangle list (`GL_TRIANGLES`), to rule out anything wrong with the calculation of your strip?

Comment: Alright, I think I'll try doing this with GL_TRIANGLES. It will probably make things a lot easier then triangle strips, and it will give me a chance to use VBOs too. :)